# How would I add a Shape.Id to a Shape in Visio

Tags: powerbi, visio

I am working with the Visio Visual in Power BI.  I need to add an Id to shapes in a Visio diagram that I want to reference in Power BI.

When I open my diagram in Visio 2019, and open show the shape data, it is empty.  There is no shape data.

[image: No Shape Data]

How would I add the prerequisite Shape Id to this shape so that I can reference it in Power BI?

Do I need to use the `Define Shape Data` to add a unique Shape Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All shapes in Visio always have ID. You cannot "define" shape ID, it is read-only. You can find the shape ID by clicking "Shape Name" button on the toolbar. Note that the "Developer" tab is not displayed by default, you may need [to turn it on](https://www.google.com/search?q=turn%20on%20developer%20tab%20in%20visio):

[image]